# Easy way to parent object hierarchy to another object in another collection

Tags: parent, collections, outliner

I'm switching to Blender from another software.
It's probably a stupid Question but maybe I'm missing something...

Lets say I have a hierarchy (or more) of objects in Collection 2 and I want to parent them to a new object (like a Empty) in another Collection 1. And I want to move all the Objects to the new Collection as well.

[image]

What I would do is:

1. select all Parent Objects
2. "Extend Child" until I have selected all childs (or "Select Hierarchy" if it's just one Hierarchy I want to move)
3. Move the Objects to Collection 1
4. Deselect the (Child) Objects/ Select all Parent Objects
   (First Find all the Parent-Objects if there are a lot of Objects in Collection 1 since it's alphabetically sorted)
5. Parent it to the Empty (Press "Shift" and move them into the Emty)

Maybe it's just my workflow but I work a lot with Emptys and Collections and I often want to move the Hierarchies to another Collection and Parent it with other Emptys or Objects and for me it seems to be a lot of steps to do.

What I would expect is more like:

1. Select all Parents
2. Move them to the new Empty in the other Collection (in the Outliner)

The Children would follow into the new Collection. The hierarchy would be preserved.

I don't want to complain about the Blender behavior - I know an object can belong to multiple Collections and stuff...

I would just be very happy if there are some tricks that I don't know yet.